# "Access denied" whenever trying to edit IMCE User-1 profile

Tags: users

After reinstalling IMCE, I am trying to see the User-1 profile by accessing the "admin/config/media/imce/profile/edit/1" URL. But it shows following error "Access denied. You are not authorized to access this page."

I have verified (URL admin/people/permissions) that administrator has privileges for IMCE module. Also rebuilding permissions is not helping here.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I changed the Drupal admin from the mysql database. I simply done undo on this operation.
Have a look in your database.